# How can I find the sum of priority for each animal type in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on pandas with python programming language. Does anyone know how I can find the sum of priority for each animal type? My program and table is shown in the link : https://ibb.co/nzXPPft. I don't know how to past my code in the text since it gets messed up.

Comment: Don't post your input data and code as an image. Edit your question and put it there as text. To mark the text as code - select it and press `ctrl`+`k`

Comment: Thank you for your feed back. I will do that from now on.

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
We expect a minimal working example of the problem, including appropriate code to trace the internal operation.

Comment: Off-site links and images of text are not acceptable; your posting must be self-contained, in keeping with the purpose of this site.
[Include your minimal data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413246/how-to-provide-a-reproducible-copy-of-your-dataframe-with-to-clipboard) as part of the example.

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.
Any PANDAS tutorial teaches you `groupby` and `sum`.

Answer (score 0):

Your example in abbreviated form:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({
    'animal':['cat','cat','dog','dog'],
    'prio':[True,False,True,True]})
```

Then get the different animals via a set and loop to get the sums:

```
animals=set(df.animal)
for a in animals:
    print(a,df[df.animal==a]['prio'].sum())
```

Or use a one-liner to create a dictionary (if you prefer):

```
{a:df[df.animal==a]['prio'].sum() for a in set(df.animal)}
```

A more elegant solution uses pandas-group by and aggregate functions, i.e.

```
df.groupby('animal').agg('sum')
```

yields

```
        prio
animal      
cat        1
dog        2
```